# Is cross entropy always larger than entropy?

Tags: python, entropy, information-theory

I am trying to understand how is cross entropy used for loss definition in classification tasks.

I am quite puzzled by the claim in Wikipedia that Cross entropy is always larger than Entropy. I came up with a very simple distribution of p(real distribution) and q(assumed distribution), and calculated the cross entropy and entropy. And found that the cross entropy in this case is less than entropy.

```
import numpy as np 
p = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
q_1 = [0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
q = [0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
def cross_entropy(p, q):
  return np.sum(-1*np.multiply(p, np.log(q)))
# Get cross entropy
print(cross_entropy(p, q))
# Get entropy 
print(cross_entropy(q_1, q))
```

What went wrong?

---

Comment: please add the tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Try this cross-entropy instead:
`print(cross_entropy(q, p))`

Cross-entropy is not symmetric in its arguments.
You can find a formula here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence
in the **Motivation** section, linking cross-entropy, entropy and KL divergence (which is always non-negative).

Basically you compared H(P,Q) and H(Q), when you should have compared:

- H(Q,P) and H(Q)
- H(P,Q) and H(P)

Doing so you would indeed see that:

- H(Q,P) - H(Q) >=0
- H(P,Q) - H(P) >=0

As a direct answer to your question: Is cross-entropy always larger than entropy?
The answer is yes if you compare the right cross-entropy with the right entropy.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment so I'll add this as an answer)

Hi,

Yes **cross entropy is always larger than entropy**.

Have a look at this blogpost to find out more: 
https://rdipietro.github.io/friendly-intro-to-cross-entropy-loss/#cross-entropy

To answer your other question: "What went wrong?"

There is a small mistake in your formula:

```
np.sum(-1*np.multiply(p, np.log(q)))
```

The formula to calculate cross entropy should be the inverse of q:

```
np.sum(-1*np.multiply(p, np.log(1/q)))
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I believe saying **cross entropy is always larger than entropy** is wrong in general, see my answer.

Comment: Hi @Tom, Interesting point. I believe that the assumption that the "right" entropies are calculated can be made, and therefore the statement can stand as is. If you'd like to see my line of argumentation, have a look at the source I am referencing! :)

Comment: Well, I believe the issue with the question here is actually that the "wrong" cross-entropy is computed.